# Selenium Webdriver iframe interactions are inconsistant

Tags: java, html, iframe, xpath, selenium-webdriver

When I enter an iframe (to provide Credit Card Details) using

```
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
```

It does its job correctly and filling in the form in the iframe and I switch out of the iframe using

```
WebElement ccInfo = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='paymentech_form']/div/button"))));
ccInfo.click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

However, the behavior of the function is inconsistent. The problem is when I am running the test in the background (minimized or hidden window) it always fails to click on the button mentioned above while the rest of the form is filled in. This problem does not prevail when I have the window open and selected.

Is there a possible work around for this?

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers? Try IE, Chrome, Firefox and see if they differ.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It is only happening in chrome. I wonder why..